# How to test user registration api with paw?

Tags: express, mean-stack, paw-app

What do I set in Paw to allow for a **login**? I have tried to use the allow cookies with to no avail.

I am working through [this tutorial](https://github.com/hwz/chirp) on Github to learn the MEAN stack. Sign up seems to be working but sign in is not.

Sign up request is:

```
GET /auth/success HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie: connect.sid=s%3A6q22s9GpNRDITB3wKBoxS1emnKCcIR3B.pI3dzqqtSBSBVgkzl7Uib4aqNAf%2Bh5iszoWDMzWPpR8
Host: localhost:3000
Connection: close
User-Agent: Paw/2.2.2 (Macintosh; OS X/10.10.3) GCDHTTPRequest
```

and the result is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 121
ETag: W/"79-56130229"
Date: Thu, 18 Jun 2015 19:52:43 GMT
Connection: close

{"state":"success","user":{"username":"admin","password":"$2a$10$AD5NBc6c6iZ09/eXuYd9oOfTEZ6MnRNYWneLy.SNPFAWf/HX1V0.6"}}
```

The user is created. But the login request fails every time; the request is:

```
GET /auth/failure HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie: connect.sid=s%3A6q22s9GpNRDITB3wKBoxS1emnKCcIR3B.pI3dzqqtSBSBVgkzl7Uib4aqNAf%2Bh5iszoWDMzWPpR8
Host: localhost:3000
Connection: close
User-Agent: Paw/2.2.2 (Macintosh; OS X/10.10.3) GCDHTTPRequest
```

the response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 72
ETag: W/"48-ed4f121"
Date: Thu, 18 Jun 2015 19:53:03 GMT
Connection: close

{"state":"failure","user":null,"message":"Invalid username or password"}
```

What it comes down to is: Is there something in paw that needs to be enabled to allow sign in testing or is my code more likely to be the problem? My code is almost verbatim from the module three part of that Github repo linked above. Any and all help would be appreciated.

Note: I did  not post code on purpose as to not clutter the question. If you need to see something I can add it just let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was not sure of my exact error I had with more trouble shooting i saw that you need to make sure that you have follow redirects on and cookies being saved.